# I can't remove items from FlatList by useState hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-native-flatlist

I am trying to remove items in FlatList by clicking on each, But it doesn't work for me, when i click on each item nothing happen and i don't get any error.
How can i fix this?

**This is my code:**(I removed unnecessary codes and styles)

```
const FoodList = () => {


  const data=  [

        { text: 'test' },
        { image: 'https://via.placeholder.com/200x100' },
        { text: 'test' },
        { text: 'test' },
        { text: 'test' },
        { text: 'test' },
        { text: 'test' },
        { text: 'test' },
        { text: 'test' },

    ]




    let [itemState, setitemState] = useState(data);




    return (


        <View>
            <FlatList
                data={data}
                keyExtractor={(item, index)=>index}
                renderItem={({ item }) => (
                    <TouchableOpacity>

                <View>
                        <Text>{item.text}</Text>
                        <Image source={{ uri: item.image}}
                        />
                    </View>
                    <Icon  
                 onPress={(index)=>setitemState(itemState=itemState.filter(item=>item.index!==index))} />
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                )}
 />
 </View>
    )}
```

Comment: `item` doesn't seem to have an index, so `item.index!==index` is not very useful.

Comment: So what is the solution?

Comment: Try `setitemState(itemState => itemState.filter((item, itemIndex) => itemIndex !== index))`

Comment: Thanks buddy, It worked but it remove all items in flat list after the touchableopacity being clicked, I want it delete just one item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, as mentioned by @Hamza Khattabi, you will need to use `itemState` in the `data` prop to actually use the updated state, otherwise there is no point of using `setitemState`, which modifies only the `itemState` state.

Secondly, I don't think `item.index` will return anything at all, and I'm pretty confident that the `onPress={(index) => {...}}` in your `Icon` element is not returning any `index` either. *You will have the use the `index` from the `renderItem` prop*, as mentioned in the docs at [this link](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist.html#renderitem).

Once you account for those changes, you can then simply filter out the `itemState` state to remove the element at the index. There are many different ways to remove the element at an index, but here is a possible solution:

```
<FlatList
  data={itemState} // Note the use of itemState
  keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
  renderItem={({ item, index }) => ( // Note the use of index
    <TouchableOpacity>
      <View>
        <Text>{item.text}</Text>
        <Image source={{ uri: item.image }} />
      </View>
      <Icon
        onPress={() => { // Note that here you can use any function to remove the element at index from the itemState list
          let _itemState = itemState.filter(
            (_item, _index) => _index !== index
          );
          setitemState(_itemState);
        }}
      />
    </TouchableOpacity>
  )}
/>
```

Let me know if this helps you by commenting below.

Comment: Thanks buddy for your help, But i am getting error in VScode, seems like that's not possible to declare a variable in onPress event, Is there any solution?

Comment: Sorry i didn't notice that you have changed onPress syntax, It worked but it remove all items into FlatList by one click

Comment: Let me see if I can reproduce this in a codepen and get back to you. It’s probably something very small that I might have missed out, and I do apologize for that.

Comment: I just noticed one more problem with your code, you are using a `TouchableOpacity` without any `onPress` prop. If you don't need `onPress` please change it to a `View`. **And you are also using `Icon` with an `onPress`, and if I assume that you are using `react-native-vector-icons` they don't have an `onPress` prop. Please make sure that you check whether an `onPress` prop is even available**

Comment: Okay so here's the Snack link: https://snack.expo.io/Skh5VfyS8 . As you can see my solution was fine pretty much, except that I overlooked the `TouchableOpacity` without any prop, and the `Icon` with an `onPress`. In this Snack, I've only made those changes to show that the logic is alright. You'll just have to make sure that the relevant props are there in your components. `Icon`s generally have a `name` prop mandatory, which is missing in your code. I'll update my answer above to reflect the changes. Please mark the question as solved if this has helped you solve your query.

Comment: Buddy your solution was completely correct in the first place, i had made a mistake and wrote ```itemState.map``` instead ```itemState.filter```. But i still don't understand how does it work, Does ```renderItem``` in ```FlatList``` use from ```map()``` method? and return true and false? How does it find out that which button I've clicked?

Answer (score 0):

Replace data variable in the data attributes by your state

```
const FoodList = () => {


    ...


    let [itemState, setitemState] = useState(data);




    return (


        <View>
            <FlatList
                data={itemState}
                keyExtractor={(item, index)=>index}
                renderItem={({ item }) => (
                 ...
 </View>
    )}
```